# Laravel 2 submit buttons in the same form

Tags: laravel

I am building a CRUD with Laravel. Each category hasMany attachments and each attachment belongsTo a category.

In the category.edit view I want to give the user the possibility of deleting the attachments (singularly) from the Category. I tried this method but it did not work:

Registering route for the attachment:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::delete('attachment/{id}', 'AttachmentController@delete')->name('attachment');    
});
```

Handling the delete building the AttachmentController@delete method:

```
class AttachmentController extends Controller
{
    public function delete($id) {

        $toDelete = Attachment::findOrFail($id);
        $toDelete->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

In the CategoryController (edit method), I fetch the attachments linked to each category to be rendered inside the view:

```
public function edit($category)
{
    $wildcard = $category;
    $category = Category::findOrFail($wildcard);
    $attachments = App\Category::findOrFail($wildcard)->attachments()->get()->toArray();
    return view('category.edit', [
        'category' => $category,
        'attachments' => $attachments
    ]);
}
```

In the view, I render the attachment and the button to delete. I am fully aware of the error of having a form inside another form, nevertheless I do not know antoher approach to submit this delete request.

```
// update Category form    
@foreach ($attachments as $attachment)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img style="width: 100%;" src={{ $attachment['url'] }} alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div>
                    <p class="general_par general_url">{{ $attachment['url'] }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <form action="{{ route('attachment', $attachment['id']) }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Image</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>                  
    @endforeach
// end of update Category form
```

Should I build a deleteAttachment method inside the CategoryController? If so, how can I still submit the Delete request? Also, if any other Model in the future will have attachments, should I build a deleteAttachment method inside each controller? That is cumbersome. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you don't like to use form, then use  tag:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ route('attachment', $attachment['id']) }}">Delete Image</a>
```

And redefine the route to `Route::get(...)`

(or maybe use ajax for POST method if that is required)